# I have a problem with the JS gcd + array work

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, greatest-common-divisor

**Hi everyone, I have a problem with a task. Here is the body of this task:**

I was working on math task and was not able to solve it :( Please, help me to implement "simple" counter.

```
function count(s, pairs) {
  return 0; // number
}
```

As first argument you will take bit mask in string s (can contains only 1 or 0). As second argument you will take array of pairs (array, which contain many arrays with length equal 2). Each pairs[q][0] !== pairs[w][0] and each pairs[h][0] is prime.

Let's define number N

```
N = (pairs[0][0] ** pairs[0][1]) *
    (pairs[1][0] ** pairs[1][1]) *
    (pairs[2][0] ** pairs[2][1]) * /*
    ..... */ *
    (pairs[pairs.length - 1][0] ** pairs[pairs.length - 1][1])
```

Your task is to calculate - how many such integer numbers k exist (0 <= k <= N), which follow next condition: greatest common divisor of (k + j and N) is 1 if s[j] === 1 AND greatest common divisor of (k + j and N) is NOT 1 if s[j] === 0.

Please, return NOT the actual number, but the number which is answer mod 1000000007.

```
// ... your solution
  // answer - task solution
  const result = answer % 1000000007;
  return result;
```

Here is my code, but it can't pass test cases:

```
    module.exports = function count(s, pairs) {
      let result = 0;
      let N = 1;
      s = s.split('');
      const gcd = (x, y) => {
        x = Math.abs(x);
        y = Math.abs(y);
        while(y) {
          var t = y;
          y = x % y;
          x = t;
        }
        return x;
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++){
        N *= (pairs[i][0] ** pairs[i][1]);
      }

      for (let k = 0; k <= N; k++){
        for (let j = 0; j < s.length; j++){
          if(s[j] == 1 && gcd(k + j, N) === 1){
            result++;
          } else if(s[j] == 0 && gcd(k + j, N) !== 1){
            result++;
          }
        }
      }

      return result % 1000000007;
    }
```